# Dynamically Create Buttons based off of SQL Column

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I am trying to write a piece of code that would pull from my SQL column and create one button per value in that column. For example, if I have column A with "test 1", "test 2", and "test 3", the code should produce three buttons which also hold the text from that value.

[image]

Here is what I have tried so far. This code only gives me one button and it is blank.

```
 private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"connstring");
            string strsql;
            strsql = "SELECT buttonID from table1 ";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strsql, conn);
            SqlDataReader reader = null;
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {           
                Button newButton = new Button();
                newButton.Text = reader["buttonID"].ToString();
                newButton.Location = new Point(1, 10);
                newButton.Size = new Size(100, 50);
                this.Controls.Add(newButton);
            }

        }
```

**UPDATE**
As mentioned in the comments, I had no way of naming my buttons, so I have added that function in. And as to why I was only seeing one button, I am assuming it is because all of the buttons are being created on top of each other, rather than displaying in rows or in columns.

Comment: We can't reproduce your issue because we don't have your schema and data. Also, when you add a button to the Controls collection, where does the button go? What are the x and y coordinates of the new button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To counter the issue I was facing, which ended up being buttons having no text and all displaying on top of each other, I added a FlowLayoutPanel and added the buttons(controls) into. Thanks for the previous answers that helped me solve this.

```
 private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"connstring");
            string strsql;
            strsql = "SELECT buttonID from table1 ";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strsql, conn);
            SqlDataReader reader = null;
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {           
                Button newButton = new Button();
                newButton.Text = reader["buttonID"].ToString();
                newButton.Size = new Size(100, 50);
                this.Controls.Add(newButton);
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(newButton);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to work on few things here.

First, check the records in the table, Do you really have 3 records? because As per your code it should work for 3 buttons.

Second, you are not setting the text of the button.

Use `using` with the `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects while initialling it.

And please define your connection string in some config file.